# implement a swipe method

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i want to know that how we can use UISwipeController in my application?

Comment: Where did you get the UISwipeController from? Google returns only a hit to this question.

Comment: He got help because people are nice, but 6 questions left unanswered leaves a mess.  @Anki, please go back to your old questions and accept answers where appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

You're probably thinking of UISwipeGestureRecognizer. Simply initialize it, call `addTarget:action:`, set the `direction` property, and finally add it to whichever view you wish should recognize the gesture.